# Store cookie connexion with Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I would like to have access to the information of an api with Axios, the problem is that Axios can't get the data. I have tested with Postman and I can access the data well.
I also noticed that Posteman stores a login cookie, I tried to reproduce with Axios but I can't.

I saw that `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true` had to be used, but it doesn't work, maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Here is my code:

```
getData() {
       axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
       let url = "***"
       axios
           .get(url)
           .then(response => {
               this.name = response
           }).catch((error) => {
               this.name = error;
           })
   }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi have you tried adding withCredentials in the options of the axios call ? Looks like this axios.get(url, {withCredentials: true}) ... Also so is it hitting the catch block , or what ? Can you explain what exactly is happening from the call? Like how if the result different from what you expected?

Comment: Hello, how do we put this option? Isn't it like in my code?

Comment: Add it as a second param to the initial axios call. Also I can't really help more than than without you answering the rest of my question

Comment: Sorry I didn't see.  What is to recover a is "network error" of the catch error part.

Comment: Can you post the exact error ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a NodeJS application?  You may need to install something like `tough-cookie`. I was shown recently that https://github.com/salesforce/tough-cookie can be used to store cookies during your axiosJS requests. This could be helpful when a cookie is assigned after the request, such as during a `302 redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

The postman cookie is juste postman stuff if you didn't set it yourself, so it might not be useful for your axios request

Careful tho, axios returns the data like `{"headers": stuff, "data": yourdata}` where Postman just displays the data that's in the "data" key

So you might want to do

```
getData() {
       let url = "***"
       axios
           .get(url)
           .then(response => {
               this.name = response.data
           }).catch((error) => {
               this.name = error;
           })
   }
```

otherwise, you can export your request Postman to code so you will see what Postman sends to the API (use the 'Code' button in Postman, under the 'Save' button)